# Tables for doctor and patients

Tags: sql, mysql

Please check if my tables specs agree with business rules. Also, please explain the differences between `CONSTRAINT`, `FOREIGN KEY` and `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY`.

I have four MySQL tables (`USER`, `NAME`, `PATIENT` and `DOCTOR`) with the following rules:

1. A patient must have a name
2. A patient can be a user
3. A doctor must have a name
4. A doctor must be a user
5. A patient can be a doctor and vice versa...
6. By 3 & 5, if a patient is a doctor that patient must be a user

---

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
userName VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE,
userId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userEmail VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
userPassword VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(userId))
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT (
patientId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
patientBirthday CHAR(8), # yyyymmdd
patientBirthplace VARCHAR(50),
patientGender TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED, # 0:male 1:female
patientBloodType TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY(patientId),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES USER(userId) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
doctorId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
nameId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY(patientId),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES USER(userId) 
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(nameId) REFERENCES USER(nameId) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
nameId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
lastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(nameId),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES USER(userId) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONSTRAINT` word used within a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` tells MySQL engine that this value is not a separate column, but rather it is applied on a column within the table.

The `FOREIGN KEY` word tells MySQL that whatever is in that field **must** reference a valid `PRIMARY KEY` from the other table on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` record, otherwise an error is raised.

`CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY` is simply how you phrase it. For more information I suggest [reading up about it in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Now for your criteria:

1. A patient must have a name: FALSE

   That one is not true, unless you added either of those two to your `CREATE TABLE PATIENT`

   - `NOT NULL` to the `userID` column and a `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES USER(userID)`
     or, preferably in my opinion:
   - `nameID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(nameID) REFERENCES NAME(nameID),`
2. A patient can be a user: TRUE
3. A doctor must have a name: TRUE
4. A doctor must be a user: TRUE
5. A patient can be a doctor and vice versa...: TRUE (via `userID`)
6. By 3 & 5, if a patient is a doctor that patient must be a user: TRUE